# sorting 2D-Array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have the following 2D-Array:

```
Array (
[ID] => Array
    (
        [0] => 150
        [1] => 250
    )

[Group] => Array
    (
        [0] => 120
        [1] => 120
    )

[Name] => Array
    (
        [0] => Name 1
        [1] => Name 2
    )

[Price] => Array
    (
        [0] => 9.99
        [1] => 11.99
    )

[Date] => Array
    (
        [0] => 12.04.2013
        [1] => 11.04.2013
    )

[SortIndex] => Array
    (
        [0] => 20
        [1] => 10
    )
```

)

and I want to sort them after the SortIndex-Array ascending. But the different Values from the Arrays are related to the others. So the association can't be changed.
How I could sort them?

Comment: look at array_multisort http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php

Comment: Not sure if this is just my thoughts but storing an 'object' accross multiple arrays on a key index can be messy. Most people would have this more as an array of 'objects' with the values stemming off each one. This makes it easier to get/move the data. Edit: See Xpundel's answer for what I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there is any reason not to convert array to more suitable form?

```
Array (
[0] => Array
    (
        [ID] => 150
        [Group] => 120
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [ID] => 250
        [GROUP] => 120
    )
....
```

Comment: Whilst this doesn't actually answer his question, I agree.

Comment: Why not... I will convert it and sort it then. Thank you!